# Kinematics Word Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

> A curling rink is approximately 35 m long from button to button.  Mr. Grover releases a rock and 20. seconds later it stops on the far button.  What was the initial velocity of the stone?  What deceleration did it undergo?

- Initial velocity = ?
- Final velocity = 0 m/s
- Time = 20 seconds
- Acceleration = ?
- Distance = 35 m

Did I forget anything because I can't use any of the formulas I learned if I'm missing two things.

Formulas
\begin{align}
v_{f} &= v_{i} + at\\
v_{f}^2 &= v_{i}^2 + 2 ad\\
d &= v_{i} t + \frac12 at^2\\
a &= \frac{v_{f} - v_{i}}{t}\\
\end{align}

Comment: You're forgetting a couple average velocity equations. Find the average velocity of the stone over the time interval, and then use that and the final velocity to find an initial velocity

Answer (score 1):

Use $d=v_i t +\frac{1}{2}a t^2$ and then substitute from the first equation that $v_i=-a t$. You get
$$d= -at^2+\frac{1}{2}at^2=-\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
from which you can infer
$$ a=-\frac{2d}{t^2}$$
Once you have the acceleration you get the initial velocity from $v_i=-a t$.